# Round up line-height

Tags: html, css

It seems that chrome round down the value of the computed `line-height`.

For instance:

`line-height:1.33` with `font-size:11px` will have computed `line-height:14px`.

Whereas the exact value is `14.66` so I would expect the line-height to equal 15px

Do you know if there is any way to force the browser to round up the computed value instead of round down?

Comment: Might I ask how did you finally go around this?

Answer (score 3):

Chrome truncates the decimals to an integer pixel value. Other browsers (FF) will round to the nearest integer pixel value. They will all use the decimal value for calculating child values though.

You could try using translateZ to force the element with the text in it to be graphics accelerated, this "may" allow sub-pixel rendering for the text. If it does work it will likely only work in Chrome.

```
#elm {
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the browser inconsistencies. I tried out on firefox and it computed as 14.66 so it doesn't even round.
I'm wondering what is the best way to have the same rendering between browser while keeping the a line-height ratio.

Comment: @pgn - unfortunately they all use different rendering engines and interpretations of the related specs. If the translateZ(0) trick doesn't work on Chrome, then you will just be deeper into crazy hacks. If there was a proverbial gun to my head I'd try rendering the text with SVG or in CANVAS.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a specific `line-height` in whatever units, e.g. `line-height: 2.2rem;` which can avoid the rounding problem if you calculate your `rem` size so that it works out to an even number in all browsers, e.g. if you set the default:

```
html {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* 10px = 1rem */
}
```

Then any time you set your line height to a value, e.g. `line-height: 2.2rem;` it would end up being exactly `22px`. This would be the same in all browsers.