# Unexpected resulting box height (computed box height smaller than line height)

Tags: css

I'm setting:

```
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 1.53846;
```

Multiplying those, [gives us 19.99998](https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=13%20*%201.53846&oq=13%20*%201.53846&gs_l=hp.3..19.855.9690.0.12718.7.7.0.0.0.0.123.707.2j5.7.0....0...1c.1j2.64.hp..0.6.622.0..0j35i39k1j0i131k1j0i20k1j0i67k1j0i22i30k1.5RVQegoygdg)

Inspecting the dev tools tells us that the computed line height is 20px - great.
But the rendered/computed [height of the box is 19px](http://jsbin.com/quyodab/1/edit?html,output)

```css
div {
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 1.53846;
}
```

```html
<div>bla</div>
```

Why?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height hope ,this link will solve your need

Comment: @Geeky its not. I asked that one too.

Comment: ok...im sorry about it..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Round up line-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281017/round-up-line-height). The answer is not marked as correct though, but testing this out, it always rounds the number. Ex. 1.53846 evaluates to 1.5, 1.789 evaluates to 1.7, and so forth in Chrome.